# AWS Instance Kernal-id

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, kernel, amazon-ami

I am running a Windows Server instance in AWS Cloud.I have created a snapshot for the same. When i'm trying to create a AMI from my snapshot it is asking **Kernel-ID** and **RAM Disk ID**. I don't know what these ID's are.

Can someone help me what these ID's are and where can i find these details in my instance.

Thanks

Comment: Have you really read the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeImages.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel ID and Ramdisk ID properties are only applicable to Linux AMI images. They're simply not used for Windows AMI images.

But, it is not possible to create a functional AMI image from a Windows-based EBS snapshot. This process only works for Linux AMI images.

To create a Windows AMI image, you must create the image directly from the EC2 instance using the `ec2:CreateImage` API, CLI, or the AWS Management Console ("Create Image" under the Actions menu).